# How to get a particular child node collection from xml to xslt

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, xsd

I have below xml file

```html
<htmlResponses>    
<resultSet></resultSet>
<referencePoint></referencePoint>
<htmlResponse></htmlResponse>
<htmlResponse></htmlResponse>
<htmlResponse></htmlResponse>
</htmlResponses>
```

And I want to get node "htmlResponse" collection in a xsl variable so I can loop through it by using XSLT.
Can anyone guide me how can I achieve this?

Comment: Generally you don't need to use a variable. If you have a '<template match="htmlResponse">' in your xslt, it will process all htmlResponse nodes automatically. Or do you need something more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Hobbes, but you could do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:variable name="responses" select="//htmlResponse"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    ... do something ...
    <xsl:for-each select="$responses/*">
      ...
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The only use case I can think of where this makes sense is if you have a lot of data, and wish to build your node set using `xsl:key` and then reuse that node set multiple times.